# which numbers among the first N Fibonacci numbers can be given in the form (1 less than a certain cube)?

Tags: java, fibonacci

I have the task to determine all numbers among the first N Fibonacci numbers that can be given in such a form: w^3 - 1.

For example, i have such a simple part of the program:

```
public static List<Long> generateFibonacciNumbers(int N) {
    List<Long> fibonacciNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    long a = 0, b = 1;
    fibonacciNumbers.add(a);
    fibonacciNumbers.add(b);

    for (int i = 2; i < N; i++) {
        long c = a + b;
        fibonacciNumbers.add(c);
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }

    return fibonacciNumbers;
}

public static boolean isW3Minus1(long num) {
    long w = (long) Math.cbrt(num + 1);
    return w * w * w - 1 == num;
}
```

The problem is that the result of this program is 0 and nothing else. I also checked manually to find such numbers, but could not do it. So i started to think that there are no such numbers except 0, but anyway, i wanted to check here too.

Comment: all numbers can be represented by `x = w^3-1` ?! that is, `w = (x+1)^(1/3)` - you probably forgot to add that `w` must be an integer - anyway the question, as posted, is not clear || BTW posted code is not complete, neither method is being called... maybe a [mre] would be appropriate

Comment: Note that the 93rd Fibonacci number is too large to fit in a long. You might have better luck using BigInteger.

Comment: Use two sets - one for the fib numbers and one for the x^3-1 numbers, then call Set.retainAll

Comment: yes, i used Set.retainAll, but still the result is only 0. Then i think it is true though

Comment: I would also post it on MathExchange. But as to prove you that there are other numbers than 0 which satisfy your condition. As I understand, you are looking for **Fn = (w^3) - 1**

Someone will prove it using induction or something

Answer (score 0):

You might find this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228934007_Fibonacci_numbers_at_most_one_away_from_a_perfect_power) interesting. Here is the abstract.

> The famous problem of determining all perfect powers in the Fibonacci sequence and the Lucas sequence has recently been resolved by three of the present authors. We sketch the proof of this result, and we apply it to show that the only Fibonacci numbers `Fn` such that `Fn ± 1` is a perfect power are `0, 1, 2, 3, 5 and 8`. The proof of the Fibonacci Perfect Powers Theorem involves very deep mathematics, combining the modular approach used in the proof of Fermat's Last Theorem with Baker's Theory. By contrast, using the knowledge of the all perfect powers in the Fibonacci and Lucas sequences, the determination of the perfect powers among the numbers Fn ± 1 is quite elementary.

For the first `1000` values I only came up with `0`. Since `BigDecimal` has no fractional power or cbrt method (like `Math.cbrt`) .  I used `Newton's method` to  compute the cube roots along with the fact that the recursive sums of the digits of candidate under test must be `0,1,8,or 9` for the number to be a perfect cube. (e.g.  19683 -> 1 + 9 + 6 + 8 + 3 = 27 -> 9 so it **may be** a perfect cube (in fact it is). The latter was used to eliminate candidates.

This was more a math problem than a programming problem. So you may want to check out the [MathExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) for more info.